# function to remove duplicate characters in a string

Tags: java, string

The following code is trying to remove any duplicate characters in a string. I'm not sure if the code is right. Can anybody help me work with the code (i.e whats actually happening when there is a match in characters)?

```
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
  if (str == null) return;
  int len = str.length;
  if (len < 2) return;
  int tail = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < tail; ++j) {
      if (str[i] == str[j]) break;
    }
    if (j == tail) {
      str[tail] = str[i];
      ++tail;
    }
  }
  str[tail] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the exercises from the book "Cracking the code interview", page 97.
"Write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string **without using any additional** buffer". NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine. An extra copy of the array is not.

Comment: @FranklinDattein can you advice please, why this code returns: abbab for the input: aabbab ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The function looks fine to me. I've written inline comments. Hope it helps:

```
// function takes a char array as input.
// modifies it to remove duplicates and adds a 0 to mark the end
// of the unique chars in the array.
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
  if (str == null) return; // if the array does not exist..nothing to do return.
  int len = str.length; // get the array length.
  if (len < 2) return; // if its less than 2..can't have duplicates..return.
  int tail = 1; // number of unique char in the array.
  // start at 2nd char and go till the end of the array.
  for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) { 
    int j;
    // for every char in outer loop check if that char is already seen.
    // char in [0,tail) are all unique.
    for (j = 0; j < tail; ++j) {
      if (str[i] == str[j]) break; // break if we find duplicate.
    }
    // if j reachs tail..we did not break, which implies this char at pos i
    // is not a duplicate. So we need to add it our "unique char list"
    // we add it to the end, that is at pos tail.
    if (j == tail) {
      str[tail] = str[i]; // add
      ++tail; // increment tail...[0,tail) is still "unique char list"
    }
  }
  str[tail] = 0; // add a 0 at the end to mark the end of the unique char.
}
```

Comment: The code is not fine; the last line causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there aren't any dupes.

Comment: Too late, but the very last line before the last bracket: **[if(tail<len) str[tail] = 0;]**

Comment: @codaddict thank you. But why do we add a 0 at the end? Does it have any special significance? Or we assume 0 to be the delimiter? What is the incoming Sting is "aa0bcedef00"? That is contains 0 (zero) in them?

Comment: @Ayusman , there is a difference between 0 and '0'. See http://www.asciitable.com/ . 0 is (null) having the ASCII code = 0 and '0' is '0' having the ASCII code = 48. Run the following program to see the difference: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = '0';
        int x = c;
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(x);
        c = 0;
        x = c;
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(x);
    }`

Comment: Pass a char [] str = 'abcabd'     This would give the output as 'abcdd'. The code doesn't work.

Comment: The problem with this solution is it does not works for Inputs like "ABSCDGAAA". It gives the out as  "ABSCDG AA" which is NOT correct. Therefor I replaced the line of code  -> str[tail] = 0; // add a 0 at the end to mark the end of the unique char.       to       if(tail<ch.length) {
   //ch[tail] = 0; 
   for(int x = tail-1; tail< ch.length; tail++) {
    ch[tail] = 0; 
   }
  }

Answer (score 34):

Your code is, I'm sorry to say, very C-like.

A Java `String` is not a `char[]`. You say you want to remove duplicates from a `String`, but you take a `char[]` instead.

Is this `char[]` `\0`-terminated? Doesn't look like it because you take the whole `.length` of the array. But then your algorithm tries to `\0`-terminate a portion of the array. What happens if the arrays contains no duplicates?

Well, as it is written, your code actually throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last line! There is no room for the `\0` because all slots are used up!

You can add a check not to add `\0` in this exceptional case, but then how are you planning to use this code anyway? Are you planning to have a `strlen`-like function to find the first `\0` in the array? And what happens if there isn't any? (due to all-unique exceptional case above?).

What happens if the original `String`/`char[]` contains a `\0`? (which is perfectly legal in Java, by the way, see [JLS 10.9 An Array of Characters is Not a String](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.9))

The result will be a mess, and all because you want to do everything C-like, and in place without any additional buffer. Are you sure you really need to do this? Why not work with `String`, `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf`, `replace`, and all the higher-level API of `String`? Is it provably too slow, or do you only suspect that it is?

"Premature optimization is the root of all evils". I'm sorry but if you can't even understand what the original code does, then figuring out how it will fit in the bigger (and messier) system will be a nightmare.

---

My minimal suggestion is to do the following:

- Make the function takes and returns a `String`, i.e. `public static String removeDuplicates(String in)`
- Internally, works with `char[] str = in.toCharArray();`
- Replace the last line by `return new String(str, 0, tail);`

This does use additional buffers, but at least the interface to the rest of the system is much cleaner.

---

Alternatively, you can use `StringBuilder` as such:

```
static String removeDuplicates(String s) {
    StringBuilder noDupes = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String si = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (noDupes.indexOf(si) == -1) {
            noDupes.append(si);
        }
    }
    return noDupes.toString();
}
```

Note that this is essentially the same algorithm as what you had, but much cleaner and without as many little corner cases, etc.

Comment: The solution using StringBuilder is certainly better but not within the boundaries of the problem. Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string
without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine.
An extra copy of the array is not.

Comment: @polygene why use substring() when you can use charAt() instead?

Comment: @DhruvGairola, I'm in agreement with you. This is a sound algorithm, but from a stylistic point of view, this method would become much more readable if `charAt(i)` was used. I like to look at code as if I'm giving it to someone who has never seen the it before, and I want them to ask minimal questions.

Answer (score 16):

Given the following question :

> Write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string **without
>   using any additional buffer**. NOTE: **One or two additional variables
>   are fine.** An extra copy of the array is not.

Since one or two additional variables are fine but no buffer is allowed, you can simulate the behaviour of a hashmap by using an integer to store bits instead. This simple solution runs at O(n), which is faster than yours. Also, it isn't conceptually complicated and in-place :

```
    public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
        int map = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if ((map & (1 << (str[i] - 'a'))) > 0) // duplicate detected
                str[i] = 0;
            else // add unique char as a bit '1' to the map
                map |= 1 << (str[i] - 'a');
        }
    }
```

The drawback is that the duplicates (which are replaced with 0's) will not be placed at the end of the str[] array. However, this can easily be fixed by looping through the array one last time. Also, an integer has the capacity for only regular letters.

Comment: I really like this solution, very C like. Conceptually a great solution, however, it does not work for normal cases. It will only work from a..z case sensitive. No spaces supported. This would work miracles in a 256bit system to process the entire ASCII range. But it does run in O(N). I still +1 this one.

Comment: @Dhruv : could you please explain how  this condition works ?-  if ((map & (1 << (str[i] - 'a'))) > 0)

Comment: @Dhruv why are you using str[i] - 'a'  and what is that symbol after map - map |

Comment: Even with the obvious limits of this usage, I really like the idea beyond this solution. C-like but didactic.

Answer (score 10):

```
private static String removeDuplicateCharactersFromWord(String word) {

    String result = new String("");

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (!result.contains("" + word.charAt(i))) {
            result += "" + word.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice trick! Using "" to convert char to string! +1 :) Do you know when we want to print a '''', what we should put in the print command?

Comment: While this code looks "clean", it is not. If the word is too long, this contains method and string concatenation is the problem where you may never realize it.

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution.

The algorithm is mainly the same as the one in the book "Cracking the code interview" where this exercise comes from, but I tried to improve it a bit and make the code more understandable:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
        // if string has less than 2 characters, it can't contain
        // duplicate values, so there's nothing to do
        if (str == null || str.length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        // variable which indicates the end of the part of the string 
        // which is 'cleaned' (all duplicates removed)
        int tail = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            
            // check if character is already present in
            // the part of the array before the current char
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (str[j] == str[i]) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if char is already present
            // skip this one and do not copy it
            if (found) {
                continue;
            }

            // copy the current char to the index 
            // after the last known unique char in the array
            str[tail] = str[i];
            tail++;
        }
                          
        str[tail] = '\0';
    }
```

One of the important requirements from the book is to do it **in-place** (as in my solution), which means that no additional data structure should be used as a helper while processing the string. This improves performance by not wasting memory unnecessarily.

Comment: +1 that's IMHO the smarter and easier to understand solution shared here that strictly satisfies the requirement of: do it in place 

(I understand this as: without using high-level framework functions, and without using big auxiliary structures potentially bigger than the original string). 

It's kind of an interview/didactic-like formulated problem and so should be the solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    HashSet<Character> charz = new HashSet<Character>();

    for(Character c : s.toCharArray() )
    {
        if(!charz.contains(c))
        {
            charz.add(c);
            //System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    for(Character c : charz)
    {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
```

Comment: You need to use a LinkedHashSet to maintain the order of characters in the original string. Also, if you are using a Set, you don't need the contains clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String removeDuplicateChar(String nonUniqueString) {
    String uniqueString = "";
    for (char currentChar : nonUniqueString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!uniqueString.contains("" + currentChar)) {
            uniqueString += currentChar;
        }
    }

    return uniqueString;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some text to this answer? We usually try not to simply send code dumps but try to explain the code's logic :)

Comment: This is actually a brilliant solution! The code essentially, tries to convert the string to a character array, and leverages 'contains' method of String class, to check if the character (in form of String), exists in 'rs' or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String s = "aabbbeeddsfre";//sample string
        String temp2="";//string with no duplicates
        HashMap<Integer,Character> tc = new HashMap<Integer,Character>();//create a hashmap to store the char's
        char [] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        for (Character c : charArray)//for each char
        {
            if (!tc.containsValue(c))//if the char is not already in the hashmap
                {
                    temp2=temp2+c.toString();//add the char to the output string
                    tc.put(c.hashCode(),c);//and add the char to the hashmap
                }
        }

        System.out.println(temp2);//final string
    }
```

instead of HashMap I think we can use Set too.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is a Java question, but since I have a nice solution which could inspire someone to convert this into Java, by all means. Also I like answers where multiple language submissions are available to common problems.

So here is a Python solution which is O(n) and also supports the whole ASCII range. Of course it does not treat 'a' and 'A' as the same:

I am using 8 x 32 bits as the hashmap:

Also input is a string array using dedup(list('some string'))

```
def dedup(str):
    map = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(len(str)):
        ascii = ord(str[i])
        slot = ascii / 32
        bit = ascii % 32
        bitOn = map[slot] & (1 << bit)
        if bitOn:
            str[i] = ''
        else:
            map[slot] |= 1 << bit

    return ''.join(str)
```

also a more pythonian way to do this is by using a set:

```
def dedup(s):
    return ''.join(list(set(s)))
```

Comment: I liked the way you saved little memory. But how can you do str[i] = '' ? isn't String immutable in python ?

Answer (score 1):

Substringing method. Concatenation is done with `.concat()` to avoid allocation additional memory for left hand and right hand of `+`.
Note: This removes even duplicate spaces.

```
private static String withoutDuplicatesSubstringing(String s){

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
          String sub = s.substring(i+1);
          int index = -1;
          while((index = sub.toLowerCase().indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))) > -1 && !sub.isEmpty()){
              sub = sub.substring(0, index).concat(sub.substring(index+1, sub.length()));
          }
          s = s.substring(0, i+1).concat(sub);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Test case:

`String testCase1 = "nanananaa! baaaaatmaan! batman!";`

Output:
`na! btm`

Answer (score 0):

Question: Remove Duplicate characters in a string
Method 1 :(Python)

```
import collections

a = "GiniGinaProtijayi"

aa = collections.OrderedDict().fromkeys(a)
print(''.join(aa))
```

Method 2 :(Python)

```
a = "GiniGinaProtijayi"
list = []
aa = [ list.append(ch) for ch in a if  ch  not in list]
print( ''.join(list))
```

IN Java:

```
class test2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

 String a = "GiniGinaProtijayi";
 List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();

       for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length() ;i++) {
           char ch = a.charAt(i);
           if( list.size() == 0 ) {list.add(ch);}
           if(!list.contains(ch)) {list.add(ch) ;}

       }//for
       StringBuffer sbr = new StringBuffer();

      for( char ch : list) {sbr.append(ch);}
      System.out.println(sbr);

    }//main

}//end
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be much easier if you just looped through the array and added all new characters to a list, then retruned that list.

With this approach, you need to reshuffle the array as you step through it and eventually redimension it to the appropriate size in the end.

Comment: Thanks ck but iam trying do the code inplace without using any additional buffer.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String s = "Javajk";
    List<Character> charz = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (!(charz.contains(Character.toUpperCase(c)) || charz
                .contains(Character.toLowerCase(c)))) {
            charz.add(c);
        }
    }
     ListIterator litr = charz.listIterator();
   while (litr.hasNext()) {

       Object element = litr.next();
       System.err.println(":" + element);

   }    }
```

this will remove the duplicate if the character present in both the case.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class StringRedundantChars {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //initializing the string to be sorted
        String sent = "I love painting and badminton";

        //Translating the sentence into an array of characters
        char[] chars = sent.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("Before Sorting");
        showLetters(chars);

        //Sorting the characters based on the ASCI character code. 
        java.util.Arrays.sort(chars);

        System.out.println("Post Sorting");
        showLetters(chars);

        System.out.println("Removing Duplicates");
        stripDuplicateLetters(chars);

        System.out.println("Post Removing Duplicates");
        //Sorting to collect all unique characters 
        java.util.Arrays.sort(chars);
        showLetters(chars);

    }

    /**
     * This function prints all valid characters in a given array, except empty values
     * 
     * @param chars Input set of characters to be displayed
     */
    private static void showLetters(char[] chars) {

        int i = 0;
        //The following loop is to ignore all white spaces
        while ('\0' == chars[i]) {
            i++;
        }
        for (; i < chars.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + chars[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static char[] stripDuplicateLetters(char[] chars) {

        // Basic cursor that is used to traverse through the unique-characters
        int cursor = 0;
        // Probe which is used to traverse the string for redundant characters
        int probe = 1;

        for (; cursor < chars.length - 1;) {

            // Checking if the cursor and probe indices contain the same
            // characters
            if (chars[cursor] == chars[probe]) {
                System.out.println("Removing char : " + chars[probe]);
                // Please feel free to replace the redundant character with
                // character. I have used '\0'
                chars[probe] = '\0';
                // Pushing the probe to the next character
                probe++;
            } else {
                // Since the probe has traversed the chars from cursor it means
                // that there were no unique characters till probe.
                // Hence set cursor to the probe value
                cursor = probe;
                // Push the probe to refer to the next character
                probe++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        return chars;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Shrivatsan : welcome to stackover flow. You picked up a very old question. It had a good answer too. You can add new answers, but include more specific details how your answer compared to others.. like memory/time complexity etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RemoveDuplicateInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ABCDDCA";
        RemoveDuplicateInString rs = new RemoveDuplicateInString();
        System.out.println(rs.removeDuplicate(s));

    }

    public String removeDuplicate(String s) {
        String retn = null;
        boolean[] b = new boolean[256];

        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {

            if (b[ch[i]]) {
                ch[i]=' ';

            }

            else {
                b[ch[i]] = true;

            }
        }

        retn = new String(ch);
        return retn;

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* program to remove the duplicate character in string */
/* Author senthilkumar M*/

char *dup_remove(char *str) 
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, l = strlen(str);
    int flag = 0, result = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
         result = str[i] - 'a';
         if(flag & (1 << result)) {
            */* if duplicate found remove & shift the array*/*
            for(j = i; j < l; j++) {
                  str[j] = str[j+1];
             }
             i--; 
             l--; /* duplicates removed so string length reduced by 1 character*/
             continue;
         }
         flag |= (1 << result);
     }
     return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RemoveCharsFromString {

static String testcase1 = "No, I am going to Noida";
static String testcase2 = "goings";

public static void main(String args[])throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    RemoveCharsFromString testInstance= new RemoveCharsFromString();
    String result = testInstance.remove(testcase1,testcase2);
    System.out.println(result);
}

//write your code here
public String remove(String str, String str1)throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {   String result=null;


       if (str == null)
        return "";


    try
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < str1.length (); i++) 
    {


        char ch1=str1.charAt(i);
        for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++)
        {
            char ch = str.charAt (j);

        if (ch == ch1)
        {
        String s4=String.valueOf(ch);
        String s5= str.replaceAll(s4, "");
        str=s5;


        }
        }

    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    result=str;
    return result;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] str = { 'a', 'b', 'a','b','c','e','c' };

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (str[i] == str[j]) {
                str[i] = ' ';
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using guava you can just do something like `Sets.newHashSet(charArray).toArray();`
If you are not using any libraries, you can still use `new HashSet<Char>()` and add your `char` array there.

Answer (score -1):

An improved version for using bitmask to handle 256 chars:

```
public static void removeDuplicates3(char[] str) 
{
  long map[] = new long[] {0, 0, 0 ,0};
  long one = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
  {
    long chBit = (one << (str[i]%64));
    int n = (int) str[i]/64;

    if ((map[n] & chBit ) > 0) // duplicate detected
        str[i] = 0;
    else // add unique char as a bit '1' to the map
        map[n] |= chBit ;
  }

  // get rid of those '\0's
  int wi = 1;
  for (int i=1; i<str.length; i++)
  {
    if (str[i]!=0) str[wi++] = str[i];
  }

  // setting the rest as '\0'
  for (;wi<str.length; wi++) str[wi] = 0;
}
```

Result: "##1!!ASDJasanwAaw.,;..][,[]==--0" ==> "#1!ASDJasnw.,;][=-0" (double quotes not included)

Answer (score -1):

This function removes duplicate from string inline. I have used C# as a coding language and the duplicates are removed inline

```
 public static void removeDuplicate(char[] inpStr)
        {
            if (inpStr == null) return;
            if (inpStr.Length < 2) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < inpStr.Length; ++i)
        {

            int j, k;
            for (j = 1; j < inpStr.Length; j++)
            {

                if (inpStr[i] == inpStr[j] && i != j)
                {
                    for (k = j; k < inpStr.Length - 1; k++)
                    {
                        inpStr[k] = inpStr[k + 1];
                    }
                    inpStr[k] = ' ';
                }
            }

        }


        Console.WriteLine(inpStr);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

(Java) Avoiding usage of Map, List data structures:

```
private String getUniqueStr(String someStr) {
    StringBuilder uniqueStr = new StringBuilder();
            if(someStr != null) {
       for(int i=0; i <someStr.length(); i++)   {
        if(uniqueStr.indexOf(String.valueOf(someStr.charAt(i))) == -1)  {
            uniqueStr.append(someStr.charAt(i));
        }
       }
            }
    return uniqueStr.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RemoveRepeatedCharacters {

    /**
     * This method removes duplicates in a given string in one single pass.
     * Keeping two indexes, go through all the elements and as long as subsequent characters match, keep
     * moving the indexes in opposite directions. When subsequent characters don't match, copy value at higher index
     * to (lower + 1) index.
     * Time Complexity = O(n)
     * Space  = O(1)
     * 
     */
    public static void removeDuplicateChars(String text) {

        char[] ch = text.toCharArray();
        int i = 0; //first index
        for(int j = 1; j < ch.length; j++) {
            while(i >= 0 && j < ch.length && ch[i] == ch[j]) {
                i--;
                j++;
                System.out.println("i = " + i + " j = " + j);               

            }

            if(j < ch.length) {
                ch[++i] = ch[j];
            }

        }

        //Print the final string
        for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
            System.out.print(ch[k]);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "abccbdeefgg";
        removeDuplicateChars(text);

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure why you have decided to post this method when there are other methods in this past that are similar to yours.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.java.exercise;

public class RemoveCharacter {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveCharacter rem = new RemoveCharacter();
        char[] ch=rem.GetDuplicates("JavavNNNNNNC".toCharArray());
        char[] desiredString="JavavNNNNNNC".toCharArray();
        System.out.println(rem.RemoveDuplicates(desiredString, ch));

    }
    char[] GetDuplicates(char[] input)
    {
        int ctr=0;
        char[] charDupl=new char[20];
        for (int i = 0; i <input.length; i++)
        {
            char tem=input[i];
            for (int j= 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (tem == input[j])
                {
                    charDupl[ctr++] = input[j];
                }

            }
        }


        return charDupl;
    }
     public char[] RemoveDuplicates(char[] input1, char []input2)
     {

         int coutn =0;
         char[] out2 = new char[10];
         boolean flag = false;
         for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < input2.length; j++)
             {

                     if (input1[i] == input2[j])
                     {
                         flag = false;
                         break;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         flag = true;
                     }

             }
             if (flag)
             {
                 out2[coutn++]=input1[i];
                 flag = false;
             }
         }
         return out2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yet another solution, seems to be the most concise so far:

```
private static String removeDuplicates(String s)
    {   
        String x = new String(s);

        for(int i=0;i<x.length()-1;i++)
            x = x.substring(0,i+1) + (x.substring(i+1)).replace(String.valueOf(x.charAt(i)), "");

        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written a piece of code to solve the problem.
I have checked with certain values, got the required output.

Note: It's time consuming.

```
static void removeDuplicate(String s) {

    char s1[] = s.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(s1);                    //Sorting is performed, a to z
                //Since adjacent values are compared

    int myLength = s1.length;           //Length of the character array is stored here

    int i = 0;                          //i refers to the position of original char array
    int j = 0;          //j refers to the position of char array after skipping the duplicate values 

    while(i != myLength-1 ){

        if(s1[i]!=s1[i+1]){     //Compares two adjacent characters, if they are not the same
            s1[j] = s1[i];      //if not same, then, first adjacent character is stored in s[j]
            s1[j+1] = s1[i+1];  //Second adjacent character is stored in s[j+1]
            j++;                //j is incremented to move to next location
        }

        i++;                    //i is incremented
    }

    //the length of s is i. i>j

    String s4 = new String (s1);        //Char Array to String

    //s4[0] to s4[j+1] contains the length characters after removing the duplicate
    //s4[j+2] to s4[i] contains the last set of characters of the original char array

    System.out.println(s4.substring(0, j+1));

}
```

Feel free to run my code with your inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution

```
public static String removeDup(String inputString){
    if (inputString.length()<2) return inputString;
    if (inputString==null) return null;
    char[] inputBuffer=inputString.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0;i<inputBuffer.length;i++){
        for (int j=i+1;j<inputBuffer.length;j++){
            if (inputBuffer[i]==inputBuffer[j]){
                inputBuffer[j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    String result=new String(inputBuffer);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I came up with the following solution. 
Keeping in mind that S and s are not duplicates. Also I have just one hard coded value.. But the code works absolutely fine.

public static String removeDuplicate(String str)
    {

```
    StringBuffer rev = new StringBuffer();  
    rev.append(str.charAt(0));

    for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < rev.length(); j++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == rev.charAt(j))
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            rev.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return rev.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't understand the logic behind the solution so I wrote my simple solution:

```
  public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {

    if (str == null) return; //If the string is null return      
    int length = str.length; //Getting the length of the string
    if (length < 2) return; //Return if the length is 1 or smaller

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){ //Loop through letters on the array

        int j;

        for(j=i+1;j<length;j++){ //Loop through letters after the checked letters (i) 

            if (str[j]==str[i]){ //If you find duplicates set it to 0

                str[j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    long map = 0;
    for(int  i =0; i < str.length() ; i++){
        if((map & (1L << str[i])) > 0){
            str[i] = 0;
        }
        else{
            map |= 1L << str[i];
        }
    }
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A O(n) solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class String_Duplicate_Removal
{

public static String duplicate_removal(String s)
    {
        if(s.length()<2)
            return s;

        else if(s.length()==2)
        {
            if(s.charAt(0)==s.charAt(1))
                s = Character.toString(s.charAt(0));
            return s;
        }

        boolean [] arr = new boolean[26];

        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {

            if(arr[s.charAt(i)-'a']==false)
                arr[s.charAt(i)-'a']=true;

            else
            {
                s= ((new StringBuilder(s)).deleteCharAt(i)).toString();
                i--;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }   

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String s = "abbashbhqa";
        System.out.println(duplicate_removal(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I [resolve](https://gist.github.com/David-Hackro/d8dad4277322f6735af4dae4a40f0b0d) a similar exercise of the book : crackring the coding interview
using recursion.

```
package crackingcodeinterview;

public class Exercise {

static String textString = "this is a random text of example!@#$%^(^452464156";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    filterLetters(0, "");
}

public static void filterLetters(int position, String letters) {
    if (position != textString.length()) {

        boolean p = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            if (letters.charAt(i) == textString.charAt(position)) {
                p = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!p) {
            letters += textString.charAt(position);
        }
        position++;
        filterLetters(position, letters);
    } else {
        System.out.println(letters);
    }
  }
}
```

Other [solution](https://gist.github.com/David-Hackro/d8dad4277322f6735af4dae4a40f0b0d/d1043816bb8dc1bb464609d571cd4ca6c1fe8afd) using substring and recursion

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    getUnicLetter("esta es una cadena con letras repetidas","");
}



   public static String getUnicLetter(String originalWord,String finalWord){
        if(originalWord.isEmpty()) return  null;
        System.out.print(finalWord);
        return getUnicLetter(originalWord.replace(originalWord.substring(0,1),""),finalWord.contains(originalWord.substring(0,1)) ? "" : originalWord.substring(0,1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will solve purpose in fast and simple code.
It gives result in `O(n)`.

```
void removeduplicate(char *str)
{
    int checker = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        int val = *(str + i) - (int)'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) continue;
        else {
            *(str + cnt) = *(str + i);
            cnt++;
        }
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    *(str+cnt) = '\0';
}
```

Comment: The question is about Java, not C. And even in C your code has issues (e.g. will only work for strings consisting only of lowercase letters).

Comment: This only works if the string has a very limited range of code points. In Java, characters are 16-bit Unicode UTF-16 values.