# Finding characters in a string

Tags: java

i'm doing an encoding program where i'm supposed to delete every character in the string which appears twice. i've tried to traverse through the string but it hasn't worked. does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

```
public static String encodeScrambledAlphabet(String str)
{
    String newword = str;
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    newword += alphabet;

    newword = newword.toUpperCase();

    for (int i = 0, j = newword.length(); i < newword.length() && j >=0; i++,j--)
    {
        char one = newword.charAt(i);
        char two = newword.charAt(j);

        if (one == two)
        {
            newword = newword.replace(one, ' ');
        }



    }

    newword = newword.replaceAll(" ", "");

    return newword;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your attempt, and we'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Firstly, why are you appending the alphabet?  Also, you're iterating from both ends of the string simultaneously.  As `i` increases, `j` decreases; so you'll only find a duplicate if one instance is as far from the front of the string as the other instance is from the back.  Thirdly, `j` should start at `newword.length() - 1` instead of `newword.length()`; otherwise the first call to `newword.charAt( j )` will be trying to look outside the end of the `String`.  Try fixing these three issues; and post again if you're still stuck.

Comment: This problem is underspecified: "delete every character in the string which appears twice" could mean "AAB becomes AB" (keep the first occurrence, delete the second one) or "AAB becomes B" (both occurrences get deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to keep only the first occurrence of the character, you can do this:

```
boolean seen[65536];
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
str = str.toUpperCase();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (!seen[c]) res.append(c);
    seen[c] = true;
}
return res.toString();
```

The `seen` array contains flags, one per character, indicating that we've seen this character already. If your characters are all ASCII, you can shrink the `seen` array to `128`.

Comment: I would use a `BitSet`, which could be a bit simpler.  Meh.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by saying deleting characters that appears twice, you mean AAABB becomes AAA, below code should work for you.

```
static String removeDuplicate(String s) {
     StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
         String s1 = s.substring(i, i + 1);
         // We need deep copy of original String.
         String s2 = new String(s);
         // Difference in size in two Strings gives you the number of
         // occurences of that character.
         if(s.length() - s2.replaceAll(s1, "").length() != 2)
             newString.append(s1); 
     }
    return newString.toString();
}
```

Efficiency of this code is arguable :) It might be better approach to count the number of occurences of character by a loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, from the code that you've shown, it looks like you aren't comparing every character in the string. You are comparing the first and last, then the second and next to last. Example:

Here's your string:
THISISTHESTRINGSTRINGABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

First iteration, you will be comparing the T at the beginning, and the Z at the end.
Second iteration, you will be comparing the H and the Y.
Third: I and X
etc.

So the T a the beginning never gets compared to the rest of the characters.

I think a better way to do this would be to to do a double for loop:

```
int length = newword.length(); // This way the number of iterations doesn't change

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
      if(i!=j){
         if(newword.charAt(i) == newword.charAt(j)){
            newword.replace(newword.charAt(i), ' ');
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm sure that's not the most efficient algorithm for it, but it should get it done.

EDIT: Added an if statement in the middle, to handle i==j case.

EDIT AGAIN: Here's an almost identical post: [function to remove duplicate characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598129/function-to-remove-duplicate-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: This does not appear to work: when `i==j` your algorithm would think it's the same letter.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize that. I added an if check for that case.