# Remove duplicate string values

Tags: java, string, replace, duplication

let s say i have a string

```
String link = "www.abc.com"
```

now i have another string

```
String actualLink = "www.abc.com//www.abc.com/content/detail.html"
```

now I need a method to check actualLink string and remove the dulpicate part with string link
for example:

```
public String removeDuplicate(String link, String actualLink){
     ....
     return actualLink;    //so the actualLink will become to     "www.abc.com/content/detail.html"
}
```

any advise? thx

Comment: `String#substring`, `String#replaceAll`

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Do you  simply want to remove all characters before the last occurence?

Comment: looks like you want to remove the prefix. still unclear...

Comment: possible duplicate of [function to remove duplicate characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598129/function-to-remove-duplicate-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
actualLink = actualLink.substring(actualLink.lastIndexOf(link));
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` if the format of your *link* string is fixed as "domain.com//domain.com/full/url.html"

```
System.out.println(actualLink.split("//")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very vague what you mean with duplicate string value. From your examples I take it you want to remove the second path segment if it is equal to the first (or perhaps multiple path segments everywhere).

I would recommend splitting the string first, and then operate on the items, e.g.

```
LinkedHashSet<String> items = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a.split("/")));
return StringUtils.join(items, "/");
```

or if just the first duplicate should be removed

```
String[] items = a.split("/");
if(items.length > 1 && items[0].equals(items[1])) {
   return StringUtils.join(items, "/", 1);
} else {
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but following will work for your example:

```
String repl = actualLink.replaceAll("(.+?)/\\1", "$1");
// repl = www.abc.com/content/detail.html
```

**EDIT:** To make it more specific you can use:

```
String rep; = actualLink.replaceAll("(" + Pattern.quote(link) + ")//\\1", "$1")
// repl = www.abc.com/content/detail.html
```