# Java program to print repeating characters in a string without duplicates in output

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Today I was trying to do a Java program to print duplicate characters in a string in which output also should not have duplicates.
for example if string input is: "aabacdceefeg"
output should not have repeating characters
ie output should be: "ace" and should not not "aacee"

```
public class programclass { 
    private static Scanner s;
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            String n, a[];
            int i,j,l;
            System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
            s= new Scanner(System.in);
            n=s.nextLine();
            a=n.split("");
            l = a.length;
            for(i=0; i<l; i++){
                for(j=i+1; j<l; j++){
                    if(a[i].equals(a[j])) {
                        System.out.println(a[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
      }
}
```

Please help me to correct this out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code do? Could you provide us with some expected output and actual output?

Comment: It should find the repeated characters and print them as a string but should contain unique in that like eg: input: "teeeseettintg" output should be "te"

Comment: use `contains()` with `subString()`

Comment: Does your code compile? `a=n.split("");`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598129/function-to-remove-duplicate-characters-in-a-string

Comment: use a list & set... for every character first check and then insert in the list... using list.contains and if it exists in the list add the char to a set.. since set by default does not allow duplicates you should be fine with this.. use wrappers in the collections

Comment: Can we compare each characters without split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that sorts the string and then uses a regular expression to remove the duplicates:

```
String string = "aabacdceefeg";
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);     
String sorted = new String(chars);
String result = sorted.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

Comment: Cornelissens Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

I think a better strategy here would be to save each used character in a set and then check to see if the letter is in the set.

```
public class programclass { 
private static Scanner s;
    public static void main(String [] args) {


        String n, a[];
        int i,j,k,l;
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
        s= new Scanner(System.in);
        n=s.nextLine();
        a=n.split("");
        l = a.length;
        for(i=0; i<l; i++){
            if(set.contains(a[i])){
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
            set.add(a[i]);
        }
```

}
}

If you only want a repeated character to print out once, add another set to keep track of letters which have already been printed.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Gauthier for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a Set for this to get the job done.
here you go:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sample {
    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n, a[];
        int i, j, k, l;
        System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextLine();
        a = n.split("");
        l = a.length;
        Set<String> noDupes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            noDupes.add(a[i]);
        }
        for (Iterator<String> it = noDupes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String f = it.next();
            sb.append(f);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```