# In Python, does a set count as a buffer?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am working through Cracking the Coding Interview (4th ed), and one of the questions is as follows:

> Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string
>   without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine.
>   An extra copy of the array is not.

I have written the following solution, which satisfies all of the test cases specified by the author:

```
def remove_duplicate(s):
    return ''.join(sorted(set(s)))

print(remove_duplicate("abcd")) // output "abcd"
print(remove_duplicate("aaaa")) // output "a"
print(remove_duplicate("")) // output ""
print(remove_duplicate("aabb")) // output "ab"
```

Does my use of a set in my solution count as the use of an additional buffer, or is my solution adequate? If my solution is not adequate, what would be a better way to go about this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `set` is good for getting unique items. But even if the order matters, `sorted(set(s))` would not return the initial order. For ex. `''.join(sorted(set('abcfbcdd')))` gives `abcdf`, though the initial order is `abcfd`

Comment: Yes 'Set' counts as additional buffer. Please see O(n) solution in the answer from @Dhruv Gairola here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598129/function-to-remove-duplicate-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Only the person administering the question or evaluating the answer could say for sure, but I would say that a set does count as a buffer.

If there are no repeated characters in the string, the length of the set would equal that of the string. In fact, since a set has significant overhead, since it works on a hash list, the set would probably take *more* memory than the string. If the string holds Unicode, the number of unique characters could be very large.

If you do not know how many unique characters are in the string, you will not be able to predict the length of the set. The possible-long and probably-unpredictable length of the set makes it count as a buffer--or worse, given the possible longer length than the string.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on v.coder's comment, I rewrote the code he (or she) was referring to in Python, and added some comments to try to explain what is going on.

`````
def removeduplicates(s):
    """Original java implementation by
          Druv Gairola (http://stackoverflow.com/users/495545/dhruv-gairola)
       in his/her answer
          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598129/function-to-remove-duplicate-characters-in-a-string/10473835#10473835
      """
    # python strings are immutable, so first converting the string to a list of integers,
    # each integer representing the ascii value of the letter
    # (hint: look up "ascii table" on the web)
    L = [ord(char) for char in s]

    # easiest solution is to use a set, but to use Druv Gairola's method...
    # (hint, look up "bitmaps" on the web to learn more!)
    bitmap = 0
    #seen = set()

    for index, char in enumerate(L):
        # first check for duplicates:
        # number of bits to shift left (the space is the "lowest"
        # character on the ascii table, and 'char' here is the position
        # of the current character in the ascii table. so if 'char' is
        # a space, the shift length will be 0, if 'char' is '!', shift
        # length will be 1, and so on. This naturally requires the
        # integer to actually have as many "bit positions" as there are
        # characters in the ascii table from the space to the ~,
        # but python uses "very big integers" (BigNums? I am not really
        # sure here..) - so that's probably going to be fine..
        shift_length = char - ord(' ')

        # make a new integer where only one bit is set;
        # the bit position the character corresponds to
        bit_position = 1 << shift_length

        # if the same bit is already set [to 1] in the bitmap,
        # the result of AND'ing the two integers together
        # will be an integer where that only that exact bit is
        # set - but that still means that the integer will be greater
        # than zero. (assuming that the so-called "sign bit" of the
        # integer doesn't get set. Again, I am not entirely sure about
        # how python handles integers this big internally.. but it
        # seems to work fine...)
        bit_position_already_occupied = bitmap & bit_position > 0

        if bit_position_already_occupied:
        #if char in seen:
            L[index] = 0
        else:
            # update the bitmap to indicate that this character
            # is now seen.
            # so, same procedure as above. first find the bit position
            # this character represents...
            bit_position = char - ord(' ')

            # make an integer that has a single bit set:
            # the bit that corresponds to the position of the character
            integer = 1 << bit_position

            # "add" the bit to the bitmap. The way we do this is that
            # we OR the current bitmap with the integer that has the
            # required bit set to 1. The result of OR'ing two integers
            # is that all bits that are set to 1 in *either* of the two
            # will be set to 1 in the result.

            bitmap = bitmap | integer
            #seen.add(char)

    # finally, turn the list back to a string to be able to return it
    # (again, just kind of a way to "get around" immutable python strings)
    return ''.join(chr(i) for i in L if i != 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(removeduplicates('aaaa'))
    print(removeduplicates('aabcdee'))
    print(removeduplicates('aabbccddeeefffff'))
    print(removeduplicates('&%!%)(FNAFNZEFafaei515151iaaogh6161626)([][][   ao8faeo~~~````%!)"%fakfzzqqfaklnz'))
`````